# How to set underline with specific color on inactive tab in tablayout? My custom view occupy max tab width.

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view, android-tablayout

I can't deal with setting custom view on TabLayout tabs. I want to set underline (like indicator on active tab) with specific color on every inactive tab. I created view in this way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/tab_layout_item"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    tools:text="All in"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="7dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

but wrap_content parameter didn't work and view occupied max tab width.

Here is my TabLayout xml:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/background_primary"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

How to create custom view for TabLayout tabs which is suited to text inside (especially when String inside is short)?

Maybe is a better way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

Inflate your tabs:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
RelativeLayout tab1 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.component_custom_tab,null);
RelativeLayout tab2 ...
```

Add id to your divider:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="7dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Set color for each tab:

```
tab1.findViewById(R.id.divider).setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.color_1));
tab2 ....
```

Add tabs in TabLayout:

```
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab1), index1);
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab2), index2);
...
```